# How to fix a NoReverseMatch in django?

Tags: python, django, templates, view, django-urls

I get the following error when I run my django app on the page

`"partner/buzzfeed/":  NoReverseMatch at /partner/BuzzFeed/
Reverse for 'video_player' with arguments '('BuzzFeed', 'fXkqhhIlOtA', 'NY Yankees: 6 Essential Pieces of Postseason Memorabilia')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.`

It looks like the right variables are being passed from the template, but is not being matched correctly with the url (I think).  Any advice on how to fix it?

## views.py

```
def partner_channel(request,partner_name):
    file = urllib2.urlopen('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/'+partner_name+'/uploads?v=2&max-results=50')
    data = file.read()
    file.close()        
    root = etree.fromstring(data)       
    entries = root.findall('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry')        
    feed=[]
    i=0 #for feed list tracking
    for entry in entries:
        #find media:group
        media = entry.find('{http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/}group')      
        #get description, title, thumbnail
        desc = media.find('{http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/}description').text
        title = media.find('{http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/}title').text
        thumbnail = media.find('{http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/}thumbnail[2]').attrib.get("url")
        video = media.find('{http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007}videoid').text
        author = entry.find('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}author').find('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}name').text
        feed.append([i,title, desc, thumbnail, video, author, url])     
        i=i+1       
    return render_to_response('reserve/templates/partner.html', {'feed':feed},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def video_player(request,author,video,title):   
    return render_to_response('reserve/templates/video_player.html', {'author':author, 'video':video, 'title':title},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

## template

```
{% for video in feed %}    
    <a href="{% url video_player feed.1.5 video.4 video.1   %}" >Link</a>
{% endfor %}
```

## urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('reserve.views',
    url(r'^partner/(?P<partner_name>[-\w]+)/$', 'partner_channel'),
    url(r'^partner/(?P<author>[-\w]+)/(?P<video>[-\w]+)/(?P<video_title>[-\w]+)/$', 'video_player'),
    url(r'^partner/(?P<author>[-\w]+)/(?P<video>\w+)/(?P<title>\w+)/$', 'video_player'),
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do one of two things:

In the template, change

`{% url video_player feed.1.5 video.4 video.1   %}`

to

`{% url reserve.views.video_player feed.1.5 video.4 video.1   %}`

Or:

Add a name to urls:

`url(r'^partner/(?P<author>[-\w]+)/(?P<video>[-\w]+)/(?P<video_title>[-\w]+)/$', 'video_player', name="video-player"),`

and change the template call to

`{% url video-player feed.1.5 video.4 video.1   %}`

Comment: When I change the template, I get the error:
Reverse for 'reserve.views.video_player' with arguments '('BuzzFeed', 'fXkqhhIlOtA', 'NY Yankees: 6 Essential Pieces of Postseason Memorabilia')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

When I rever the template back and change the url/template (2nd option):
NoReverseMatch at /partner/BuzzFeed/
Reverse for 'video-player' with arguments '('BuzzFeed', 'fXkqhhIlOtA', 'NY Yankees: 6 Essential Pieces of Postseason Memorabilia')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Comment: `feed.1.5`, `video.4`, etc need to be in `''` if they are string

Comment: When I do 'feed.1.5' 'video.4' and 'video.1' in the template I get the same error as above with the ending: '(u'feed.1.5', u'video.4', u'video.1')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Comment: 1 sec.. You need to modify your regex. Your regex accepts only - and alphanumerics.. You need to to modify it to accept `.` too

Comment: In the data I'm passing ('NY Yankees: 6 Essential Pieces of Postseason Memorabilia) there isn't a period anywhere but there is a ":".  How do I change my regex to allow for this?

Comment: are you saying `feed.1.5` `video.4` `video.1` are variable names?

Comment: Yes; they are variables that are accessed via the for loop in the template.  The total list is feed, but each element is video in the for loop.

Comment: `(?P<author>[:-\w]+)` should work, if that does not, just escape the `:`